# Displaying system information on Gnome 3 desktop

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I am looking for some extension which will display all system information such as CPU usage, temperature, Internet usage, running processes etc.

I would like to see all of the output continuously updated on my desktop. I run Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit with Gnome 3

I know there are Gnome 3 extensions, but most of them (at least what I checked) display only some information on the bar. I am looking for complete set of possible informations and displaying them as a desktop background

Does anyone know something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This conky tutorial is pretty good: [Install Conky Lua On Ubuntu](https://www.unixmen.com/install-conky-lua-ubuntu-14-0413-1013-04-debian-fedora-linux-mint-opensuse/). It's quoted here to avoid link rot:

> First of all we need to install conky, you can do that by:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install conky
> ```
>
> Secondly download `conky-lua` from [here](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Conky+lua?content=139024)
>
> Then, go to the directory where you have downloaded the Conky-lua zip
>   file and extract it. All files will be extracted in a folder called
>   Conky-lua.
>
> [image: Image courtesy of www.unixmen.com]
>
> Go to the folder and pick a file and extract it depending upon your
>   distribution. As I use Ubuntu desktop, I extracted the file `Conky
>   ubuntu-lua.tar.gz`.
>
> This will be extracted in a folder called `Conky ubuntu-lua`. Go to
>   the directory, find the file `conkyrc`, and rename it to `.conkyrc`.
>   Make sure you have put the dot(.) at the beginning of the file.
>
> [image]
>
> Now, move the renamed file `.conkyrc` to your home directory. Hence,
>   we have put the dot(.) at the beginning, this file will not be
>   visible. To make sure this file is moved to the home directory, go to
>   `View -> Show Hidden files` in your file manager.
>
> Then, create a new folder called `.conky` in the home directory, and
>   copy the other 2 files to this folder (`new-ubuntu-logo.png` and
>   `clock_rings.lua`).
>
> Now we have to mention the actual path of `clock_rings.lua` file in
>   the `.conkyrc` file. Open the file `.conkyrc` in any text editor,
>
> ```
> nano ~/.conkyrc
> ```
>
> Find the line and change the path to the new one in the home folder.:
>
> ```
> lua_load /~.lua/scripts/clock_rings.lua
> ```
>
> And, change it to:
>
> ```
> lua_load ~/.conky/clock_rings.lua
> ```
>
> Save and close the file. We’re done. Open terminal and run conky using
>   the following command:
>
> ```
> conky -c ~/.conkyrc &
> ```
>
> Now, look at your Ubuntu desktop. The conky-lua theme will be running
>   and displaying all details such as date and time, usages of CPU, RAM,
>   net, disk and swap etc.
>
> [image]

(All images courtesy of https://www.unixmen.com)